# If any value equals a specific value

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm working on a workflow, and I would like to send an automatic email when a item is submitted to a sharepoint list. I have the email portion figured out, but what I need is there to be a flag marker of some sort in the subject line (right now for sake of example it's just "[*]" at the beginning of the subject line) to indicate whether an item added to a list contains an attachment(s) or not. Initially this worked with an "If else" condition where "if attachments equals true then send email template, else (null) send another email template" where one template will contain the subject line flag and another will not. However, on mobile - I encountered an issue where even though I'm attaching something (either a document or photo) it's not recognizing the attachment in the workflow. You can visit the list item in sharepoint and it'll show the attachment properly, but it will not send the proper email template indicating that attachments = true. This works as designed on desktop, not mobile.

Instead, I would like to have it where if any value from a drop down list equals value "Attached" for ANY of the drop down values, it displays the attachment flag in the subject line. I have several drop down menus with the value "Attached" as a valid option, so I would like it to test across multiple options. Is this something that is possible?[image: This is one example of multiple columns that could contain the value of "Attached"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add additional conditions to check by simply clicking another condition. The logic can be changed between `and` and `or`.

[image]

From there you can add each field that you want to check the value of. By using the logical `or` any condition that is true will cause the entire expression to be true.

For an alternative approach you could use `Call HTTP Web Service` action with a request for the current items attachments then check the results.

[image]

Check the request for any items in the result. It should return the `ServerRelativeUrl` and `FileName` if it has an attachment.

Comment: This is much more simple than what I had envisioned. Thank you very much!